# I changed bash to zsh and curl -o stopped working with this error: curl: (56) response reading failed (errno: 36)

Tags: bash, curl, terminal, zsh

I used to run this curl -o command in Terminal in bash and it worked just well.

```
curl -o '/Users/tomasjelinek/Google Drive/Můj disk/ISP_Orders_last.csv' 'ftp://Tomas%20Jelinek:PASSWORD@XX.XX.XXX.X/Marketing/Reports/60%20ISP%20Report/ISP_Orders_last.csv'
```

One day just out of the blue, Terminal told me: The default interactive shell is now zsh
with this error:

```
curl: (56) response reading failed (errno: 36)
```

I changed my default settings to zsh, but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: `curl` error 56 ("Failure in receiving network data.") is generally a network problem, and shouldn't have anything at all to do with the shell. Also, you don't need to change your shell to zsh. That's what Apple recommends, but bash still works fine.

Comment: Changing your shell means different startup files are loaded, maybe `.zshrc` instead of `.bashrc`. If you set variables in these files that affect the way curl works, then you need to set the same variables in `.zshrc`. In the case of curl, if you need to access the internet through a proxy, you may need to set `HTTP_PROXY` or `HTTPS_PROXY` variables.